# SSIS: How to create custom log files?

Tags: ssis

I would like to create a custom log errors .  I followed the tutorials on msdn but to no avail.  I am just trying to log "Hello" to a file called test.txt.  I have enabled logging and enabled the script task to handle the log i set up.

Any suggestions/tutorials/advice?

I would certainly appreciate it!

Danke

Answer (score 0):

General steps are

- Create the log connection manager
- Create whatever task you are wanting to log (or you can do it for the entire package)
- In the Event Handlers tab for that task or the package, place whatever you want to happen on the canvas.  If you want to write to a text file, I'd create a script task that would write to your text file.  The file location could be a variable passed from the package so you don't have to go into the script task to change that configuration.

Info on setting variables in the script task:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135941.aspx